# Raw Select Laravel - 'ST_Transform' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: laravel, postgis

I am try do run this PostGIS query in Laravel inside a model without success:

```
DB::table('public.' . $this->getTable())
        ->selectRaw('ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(geom, 4326)) as geom')
        ->where('id', $this->id)
        ->get()
```

I get this error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 'ST_Transform' is not a recognized built-in function name.

The query works fine in console.

How can I solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try prefix 'public' for example:
`Model::selectRaw('*, public.st_transform(geom, 4326) as geom')->get();`